# Issues using Retrofit2 to call GitHub REST API to update existing file

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2, github-api

I'm attempting to use Retrofit to call the [GitHub API to update the contents of an existing file](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents), but am getting 404s in my responses. For this question, I'm interested in updating [this file](https://github.com/blakewilliams1/blakewilliams1.github.io/blob/master/qr_config.json). Here is the main code I wrote to try and achieve this:
**GitHubUpdateFileRequest**

```
public class GitHubUpdateFileRequest {
  public String message = "Some commit message";
  public String content = "Hello World!!";
  public String sha = "shaRetrievedFromSuccessfulGETOperation";
  public final Committer committer = new Committer();

  private class Committer {
    Author author = new Author();
    private class Author {
      final String name = "blakewilliams1";
      final String email = "blake@blakewilliams.org";
    }
  }
}
```

**GitHubUpdateFileResponse **

```
public class GitHubUpdateFileResponse {
  public GitHubUpdateFileResponse() {}
}
```

**GitHubClient**

```
public interface GitHubClient {
  // Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content
  // WORKS FINE
  @GET("/repos/blakewilliams1/blakewilliams1.github.io/contents/qr_config.json")
  Call<GitHubFile> getConfigFile();

  // https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents
  // DOES NOT WORK
  @PUT("/repos/blakewilliams1/blakewilliams1.github.io/contents/qr_config.json")
  Call<GitHubUpdateFileResponse> updateConfigFile(@Body GitHubUpdateFileRequest request);
}
```

**Main Logic**

```
// Set up the Retrofit client and add an authorization interceptor
UserAuthInterceptor interceptor =
    new UserAuthInterceptor("blake@blakewilliams.org", "myActualGitHubPassword");
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
    new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor);

Retrofit.Builder builder =
    new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();

client = retrofit.create(GitHubClient.class);

// Now make the request and process the response
GitHubUpdateFileRequest request = new GitHubUpdateFileRequest();
client.updateConfigFile(request).enqueue(new Callback<GitHubUpdateFileResponse>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<GitHubUpdateFileResponse> call, Response<GitHubUpdateFileResponse> response) {
    int responseCode = response.code();
    // More code on successful update
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<GitHubUpdateFileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Unable to update file" + t.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
});
```

**What currently happens:**
Currently, the success callback is triggered, but with a response code of 404 like so:

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://api.github.com/repos/blakewilliams1/blakewilliams1.github.io/contents/qr_config.json}

Has anyone else encountered this? I first thought it was a problem with including '/content/' in the URL but I do the same thing for reading the file contents request and it works fine (also uses same URL just a GET instead of PUT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone interested in doing this in the future, I figured out the solution.**

1. I needed to revise the request object structure
2. Rather than using an authentication interceptor, I instead added an access token to the header. [Here is where you can create access tokens for Github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), you only need to grant it permissions to the 'repos' options for this use case to work.

This is what my updated request object looks like:

```
public class GitHubUpdateFileRequest {
  public String message;
  public String content;
  public String sha;
  public final Committer committer = new Committer();

  public GitHubUpdateFileRequest(String unencodedContent, String message, String sha) {
  this.message = message;
  this.content = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(unencodedContent.getBytes());
  this.sha = sha;
  }

  private static class Committer {
    final String name = "yourGithubUsername";
    final String email = "email@yourEmailAddressForTheUsername.com";
  }
}
```

Then from my code, I would just say:

```
GitHubUpdateFileRequest updateRequest = new GitHubUpdateFileRequest("Hello World File Contents", "This is the title of the commit", shaOfExistingFile);
```

For using this reqest, I updated the Retrofit client implementation like so:

```
// https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/vnd.github.v3+json"})
@PUT("/repos/yourUserName/yourRepository/subfolder/path/to/specific/file/theFile.txt")
Call<GitHubUpdateFileResponse> updateConfigFile(
    @Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Body GitHubUpdateFileRequest request);
```

And I call that interface like this:

```
githubClient.updateConfigFile("token yourGeneratedGithubToken", request);
```

And yes, you do need the prefix "token ". You could hardcode that header into the interface, but I pass it in so that I can store it in locations outside of my version control's reach for security reasons.